# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'regenerate')

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, passport.js

I am running into this error. Here is my server file and my user and passport middleware.
The only time the error comes up is on logout. when i am sending  a GET request to /logout.
The error is

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'regenerate')
at Immediate. (C:\Users\nphil\Documents\code\bugTracker\node_modules\passport\lib\sessionmanager.js:83:17)
at process.processImmediate (node:internal/timers:478:21)

Server

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const config = require('./config/config');
const port = config.port;
const password = encodeURIComponent("alskfdjoicalfno;h");
const URI = 'moPh8bJafdikjasdf;lkjaaf;kj4zmOJqx3OA@cluster0.g2mze.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority';
const cors = require("cors")
const passport = require('./config/passport');
const session = require('express-session');
const flash = require('connect-flash');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const app = express();


app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.json());

app.use(cookieParser('cownow'));

app.use(cors({credentials: true, origin: 'http://localhost:5000'}));



app.use(session({
    secret: 'cownow',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: { secure: false }
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(flash());

app.use(require('./routes/user'))
app.use(require('./routes/Auth'))
app.use(require('./routes/home'))
app.use(require('./routes/stage'))
app.use(require('./routes/bug'))
app.use(require('./routes/collection'))
app.use(require('./routes/project'))
app.use(require('./routes/task'))
app.use(require('./routes/timeCard'))



mongoose.connection.on('connected', () => {
    console.log('Mongoose is connected!!!!');
})

mongoose.connect(URI, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })



app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.header(
      "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
      "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"
    );
    res.header(
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Cache-Control, Origin, Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Authorization"
    );
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
    if ("OPTIONS" === req.method) {
      res.sendStatus(200);
    } else {
      next();
    }
  });

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('Server running on port: ' + port);
})
```

User Model

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    password: String,
    admin: Boolean,
    active: Boolean,
    projectIds: [mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId]
});



// Hash the password before saving it to the database
userSchema.pre('save', async function(next) {
    const user = this;

    if (user.isModified('password')) {
        user.password = await bcrypt.hash(user.password, 8);
    }
    next();
});

// Method to validate password
userSchema.methods.validPassword = async function(password) {
    return await bcrypt.compare(password, this.password);
};

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

Passport config

```
const passport = require('passport');
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const User = require('../models/user'); 

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {

    done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(async (id, done) => {
    try {
        let user = await User.findById(id);
        done(null, user);
    } catch(err) {
        done(err);
    }
});

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
    async function(username, password, done) {
        try {
            let user = await User.findOne({ username: username });
            if (!user) {
                return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect username.' });
            }
            if (!user.validPassword(password)) {
                return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect password.' });
            }
            return done(null, user);
        } catch(err) {
            return done(err);
        }
    }
));
module.exports = passport;
```

Authorization route

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const passport = require('passport');
const User = require('../models/user'); 

router.get('/auth', (req, res, next) => {
    res.send('This is get in auth.js');
})

router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', {
    successRedirect: '/',
    failureRedirect: '/login',
    failureFlash: true
}));

router.get('/logout', (req, res) => {
    req.logout(() => {});
    req.session.destroy(err => {
        if (err) {  
            return res.send(err);
        }
        // Moved this inside the callback
        res.clearCookie('connect.sid');
        res.status(200).send('You are logged out'); // Here, req.user will be undefined since the user is already logged out
    });
});

router.post('/register', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body)
    const user = new User({
        username: req.body.username,
        password: req.body.password,
    });
    user.save().then((user) => {
        return res.redirect('/home');
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
        return res.status(400).send(err.message);
    });
});

router.put('/auth', (req, res, next) => {
    res.send('This is put in auth.js');
})

router.delete('/auth', (req, res, next) => {
    res.send('This is delete in auth.js');
})


module.exports = router;
```

I researched online and they said the issue was that the middleware was being called in the incorrect order. I verified I am calling them in the correct order.